# $\lim_{x\to0} |x|^{\frac{3}{2}}\ln|x|$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to0} |x|^{\frac{3}{2}}\ln|x|$$

I don't understand why this limit is equal to 0. What can I use on this limit to get rid of the $0\cdot-\infty$ form?

Comment: rewrite $\text{ln}\vert x\vert$ into $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\text{ln}\vert x\vert}}$ and then use L'Hôpital as you have "0/0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\exp(|x|^{3/2} \ln |x|)= \exp(\ln|x|)^{|x|^{3/2}} = |x|^{(|x|^{3/2})} \to 1$$

using the standard limit $|x|^{|x|} \to 0 $

Hence by continuity of $\exp$, your limit goes to $\ln(1) = 0.$